# Trying to Create Instance by Using String name i.e a class name bt GetType method returns null

Tags: c#, .net

I Trying to Create Instance by Using String name i.e a class name bt GetType method returns null

```
namespace DocSys
{
  public class Documents
  {
   Control ctlControl = new Control();
    //strProgID= DocCtl.Button
   Type type = Type.GetType(strProgID);  // null Value in Type type
   ctlControl  = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
  }
}
```

At present strProgID contains DocCtl.Button (Button is a user control and it namespace is DocCtl)

Can i create a object of strProgID

Comment: see this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2005/08/21/454213.aspx

Comment: *As you can read in the docs*, [`GetType(string)` requires that you pass the *assembly-qualified name* of the type.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in-order to get that type from tha string you need to use the fully qualified name of that type , should be something like `DocCtl.Button,AssemblyThatContainsThisNamespace`